# TRibbon Large Image problem

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, ribbon-control

I am writing an Application in Delphi 2010 and trying the new TRibbon control for the first time.

All works fine, however I have a small problem:

I have added a 64x64 Bitmap in a TImageList which is assigned to my TActionManager control.
I have then added my Action to a group in the TRibbon, and set the large image from my TImageList. The Image displays but is not centered correctly, instead it is displayed to half and i look text "Action" in it, not under.

How can I solve this problem? I am new on this community, i have tried to upload screenshot but not understood as to do it.

Thanks very much.

Danny.

---

### UPDATE

Hello i have done all that you told, and is correct; i have images 64x64 pixel. Trying maybe i have understood where is problem. 
Shortly, in actionmanager if i set as style "Default platform" or "Standard" or "XP Style" i see images correctly. But when i run application it turn back to "Ribbon - Luna" and truncate image to half. 
I have tried to do it to runtime but nothing, he set every "Ribbon - Luna". Is a bug? Or i mistake something? I have saw that in ribbon control in style i can choose only value as: "Ribbon - Luna" or "Ribbon - Obsidian" or "Ribbon - Silver" and not other.
I have tried to use the toolbar control, and if i set "Ribbon - Luna" as style i have same problem that in ribbon control; if i set "Default platform" or "Standard" or "XP Style" all work correctly.
So i have thinked that problem not is in ribbon control or in toolbar control, but in actionmanager control; but not understood as solve it, i have tried to study on it, but not solved :( Can help me better? I hope that this info can to help you more to solve mine problem. Thanks you very much.

Comment: It might be worth you checking the demo folder for a Ribbon Application, ie: ..\Samples\Delphi\VCL\RibbonControls.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have the image list set to Width = 64 and Height = 64 BEFORE you use the 'Add' operation to read in your image. Any menu that now uses this image list should show your 64x64 image fine. If it doesnt, then you may be loading an icon which has multiple image sizes and this may be the problem. Check the image you are loading by downloading GIMP and open it to check (and if necessary delete) unwanted layers of other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon control is designed to accept large images that are 32 x 32, 64 x 64 is too large. Try using smaller images (and making sure the imagelist has the same dimensions).

N@